# Mejor opción para base de datos android app

Tags: android, base-de-datos, app, backend

Estoy por comenzar el desarrollo de una app Android estilo Uber donde habrá clientes con sus respectivos perfiles y prestadores de un servicio en particular también con sus perfiles. Geolocalización, pagos con tarjetas, etc. Imaginemos que estamos hablando de Uber.

El frontend de la app será hecho con Javascript + React Native.

Con el backend es donde mas dudas tengo.
No sé si será conveniente usar Firebase (leí que no es tan recomendado), Java (Spring), Python (Django), el mismo JS ya que lo uso para el frontend (NodeJS) u otras alternativas. Y qué tipo de base de datos debería crear.

La verdad es que siempre me dedicado a aprender (nunca trabajé profesionalmente) sobre todo lo relacionado al frontend y soy bastante nuevo con el backend y tengo muchas dudas.

Muchas gracias, saludos!

Comment: Actualmente soy freelancer por la tarde en [*MiAutobus*](https://miautobus.com/), una aplicacion similar a la que quieres realizar, te comento que trabajamos con Firestore y que es una de las mejores herramientas hasta el momento para nuestro backend, ya que no requerimos tener los datos distribuidos en lugares distintos y nos ofrece muchisimas herramientas como [Google Analytics](https://firebase.google.com/products/analytics/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIka3dmaqD3QIViyaGCh3fSgsBEAAYASAAEgLE0_D_BwE), [tests A/B](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ab-testing/?hl=es-419), [notificaciones push](https://fireb

Comment: Si tienes alguna duda franco contactame, no entra en comentarios la respuesta y no la puedo recuperar desde abajo, saludos